# Parsing JObject properly

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I would like to parse the following json

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "data": {
  
    "xyz": [
      [
        3.5927680391473826,
        0.5641835941824296,
        -0.88546609584117
      ],
      [
        3.5885032091080853,
        0.7537851201209402,
        -0.9748245317650808
      ]
    ],
    "xy": [
      [
        479,
        32
      ],
      [
        435,
        85
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using the following code to do so,

```
resultantData = JObject.Parse(inputString)
List<float> xyz = resultantData["data"]["xyz"].Value<List<List<float>>>();
List<int> xy = resultantData["data"]["xy"].Value<List<int>>();
```

Unfortunately, the above code wasn't able to parse the JSON properly. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the exact error or issue?  My guess is that you need `List<List<float>> three_d_pt` and the other one should also be a list of lists.

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors. It just stops working. Since I use unity , it's hard to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have list of lists , not just list

```
List<List<float>> xyz = resultantData["data"]["xyz"].ToObject<List<List<float>>>();
List<List<int>> xy = resultantData["data"]["xy"].ToObject<List<List<int>>>();
```

you can use it like this

```
if (xyz != null && xyz.Count > 0)
{ 
    List<float> xyz1 = xyz[0];
}
```

if you want to put everything in one pile, I don't think that it is a good idea , you have to try this

```
List<float> xyz = resultantData["data"]["xyz"].ToObject<List<List<float>>>()
.SelectMany(i=> i).ToList();
List<int> xy = resultantData["data"]["xy"].ToObject<List<List<int>>>()
.SelectMany(i=> i).ToList();
```

Comment: should it be double?

Comment: It is up to you, I don't know what type you need  to use in Unity. You can change it to double or decimal without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it using [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(inputString);

public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public long Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("xyz")]
    public List<List<double>> Xyz { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("xy")]
    public List<List<long>> Xy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what if the data is optional?